# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

Can not run my `awesome.py` cause:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'


(incaelum) C:\Users\inc\Desktop\pruebas\STR_SEARCH>python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tqdm
>>>
```

As u can see i can run python and `import tqdm` with no errors
I used `pip`, `pip3`, `conda` to install `tqdm` inside my envoriment:
installation suscesful

I also installed `tqdm` from anaconda environment manager. no errors as well 
but when i run the program i get always the same:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Am running the py file from my envoriment and getting same error.

Anyone can deal with this?

Comment: How are you running your code? What command are you using?

Comment: Use ```virtualenv```

Comment: There is quite a lot of missing details but my guess is that where you installed ``tqdm`` and where you a running it is not the same. The ``(incaelum)`` in front if your command prompt seems to indicate that you are inside a ``virtualenv`` are you running you ``awsome.py`` inside this same ``virutalenv``?

Comment: yes i am running: py awesome.py inside my env (incaelum)